# heightAnchor.constraint does not work (Apple FoodTracker Tutorial using Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I've been doing a iOS tutorial from Apple; Start Developing iOS Apps.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementingACustomControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH19-SW1

In the tutorial, I added a button which has the size constraint of 44.0x44.0 on a Horizontal stack view.
However, the simulator shows a larger button.

[looks the size constraints do not work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnNHW.png)

My code is below. Can you give advices to fix?

```
class RatingControl: UIStackView {
    //MARK: Initialization
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupButtons()
    }
    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupButtons()
    }

    //MARK: Private Methods
    private func setupButtons() {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        // Add constraints
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
        addArrangedSubview(button)
    }
}
```

The problem was fixed by changing the property of the StackView.

Comment: What are the constraints, Alignment and Distribution properties of your `RatingControl` (which is a subclassed `UIStackView`)?

Comment: @DonMag Both Alignment and Distribution are set to Fill.

Comment: ok - Stack Views can *seem* to mess with sizing. I say "seem to" because they are behaving as designed, it's just not always clear how they were designed. Changing Alignment to Leading should fix the width... and changing Distribution to Equal Spacing should fix the height... but, depending on how you have the Constraints set, you might need additional tweaking.

Comment: Whoops... is Axis set to Vertical? If not, height and width may be backwards...

Comment: By changing Alighment to Leading and Distribution to Equal Spacing properly fixed the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same issue. It was because I didn't drag the new Horizontal StackView into the existing Vertical StackView. Instead, I dragged it into the main View.  If you look at the Document Outline, the the new StackView should be a child of the first Vertical StackView, and just under the Photo Image View.

It's in the instructions, but it was unclear for me.

- [Correct - Screen shot of IB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCt14.png)
- [Wrong - Screen shot of IB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp8x8.png)

Comment: This also soved the problem. the instruction is not clear for me.